# is "following" a reserved keyword in Hive?

Tags: hive, keyword

Hive command - create table table_name (accountId string,name string,following string);
throws following exception,

[main] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver  - FAILED: ParseException line 2:198 cannot recognize input near 'following' 'string' ',' in column specification
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 2:198 cannot recognize input near 'following' 'string' ',' in column specification

In the below link,"following" is not mentioned in the reserved keywords list,
http://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/faq

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be in the reserved key word list. However you can use the below query to create the column name following.

```
create table test (accountId string,name string,`following` string);
```

Comment: any other workaround to resolve such issues? exchange is another reserved keyword.If I am processing a text file which contains word and some count.so I need to load my hive table like (name String,exchage String....). We cannot predict what all keeps can apper. How to deal with that?